# 14.04 and Laptop keypad

Tags: keyboard, numpad

On my laptop keyboard in Windows, if numlock is off, 7=Home 1=End 9=PageUp 3=PageDown.

But in Ubuntu, it types strange characters. My end key (1) types out ~.

What can I do to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try turning numlk on and off? Use:

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>numlk</kbd>

If that doesn't work, try changing your keyboard layout in system settings.

Comment: fn + numlock is no use. :(